# JAXB - @XmlJavaTypeAdapter on a WS return value

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jaxb

I am actually trying to build a process for refactoring a large number of existing webservices.
The idea is to use JAXB/JAXWS tools to automate this as much as possible.

Most of our issues are resolved except for one blocking problem : 
JAXB by default serializes boolean types as "true"/"false". I need those values to be "0"/"1".

On the existing classes of our codebase, I'm trying to use as much annotations as possible, and of course not modifying at all what is auto generated by JAX tools.
After adding correct annotations, I run wsgen so it generates JAX-WS necessary classes for deployment.

Here is a concrete example of an annotated webservice method:

```
public @WebResult(name = "success")
  @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value = lu.ept.common.xmlSerializers.BooleanAdapter.class, type = boolean.class)
  boolean modifyStatus(@WebParam(name = "processActionId") String processActionId, @WebParam(name = "newStatus") int newStatus)
        throws BusinessMessage, SystemMessage {
```

When running wsgen, it picks up correctly the WebResult and WebParam attributes, but it refuses to use my XmlJavaTypeAdapter.

My question is very simple : has someone managed to use XmlJAvaTypAdapter annotation on a webservice method return value? Is it possible?

(on the documentation I read, I haven't seen anything concerning the use of that annotation on return values)

Actually the only solution I have found is to manually add the XmlJavaTypeADapter annotation to the classes generated by wsgen. This is not a viable solution, because those classes will be generated after each build...

Comment: One detail that could matter : when calling wsgen, it's using JAX-WS RI from IBM.